# Gmap + Primefaces: Map Location from full address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsf-2, primefaces

Hy,

well i'm using a JSF2 project with primefaces 3.0 and GMmap component.

As we know this component accepts just location, but i need to work with address as well..

For exemple, instead of using a Lat,Log I would like to pass the full address (street, state, city..) to get the map.

I would like to know if there is any workaround, like:

1. Is it possible to call a javascript just after the p:gmap to change the location based in the address?
2. Is it any Java API to call using a adress and receiveing a Lat,Log ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

This process is known as geocoding. Please see the documentation for it on the [Google Maps API page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#Geocoding).

Comment: You can get the underlying google maps from PrimeFaces Map widget and use geocoding api directly.

Comment: yes, actually is geocoding.. not the reverse one. But my doubt is how should I use the call from google api directly to the Primefaces GMap component. Ex.: I use a geocoder.geocode passing the address.. now how use it in prime component?

Comment: No reverse geocoding support yet?